# construct Jooq stream is too slow

Tags: scala, stream, jooq

I am using Scala.

I tried to fetch all data from a table with about 4 million rows. I used stream and the code is like

```
val stream Stream[Record] = expression.stream().iterator().asScala.toStream
stream.map(println(_))
```

**expression** is SelectFinalStep[Record] in Jooq.

However, the first line is too slow. It costs minutes. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Streams are kept in memory in order to be re-traversed. You should directly use iterators if you only plan to consume once. You should consider using a more modern streaming framework, or Slick streaming actions to play with the database. 

I'm pretty sure calling `stream` on that expression is trying to fetch too many database rows, you need a paged system that can allow you to fetch chunks of the result set "just in time", not in full ahead of time, and specify a fetch size, so you only deal with 10k records at any given time, let's say, instead of 4 million.

Comment: @flavian: Why recommend slick when this can be done perfectly easily with jOOQ?

Comment: I am using stream to avoid using too much memory. It won't save any memory as you say.  @flavian Any suggestions to archive that?

Answer (score 3):

#### Use the Stream API directly

If you're using Scala 2.12, you don't have to transform the Java stream returned by `expression.stream()` to a Scala `Iterator` and then to a Scala `Stream`. Simply call:

```
expression.stream().forEach(println);
```

While jOOQ's [`ResultQuery.stream()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#stream--) method creates a lazy Java 8 [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html), which is discarded again after consumption, Scala's [`Stream`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.html) keeps previously fetched records in memory for re-traversal. That's probably what's causing most performance issues, when fetching 4 million records.

#### A note on resources

Do note that `expression.stream()` returns a resourceful stream, keeping an open underlying `ResultSet` and `PreparedStatement`. Perhaps, it's a good idea to explicitly close the stream after consumption.

#### Optimise JDBC fetch size

Also, you might want to look into calling [`expression.fetchSize()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchSize-int-), which calls through to JDBC's [`Statement.setFetchSize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize-int-). This allows for the JDBC driver to fetch batches of N rows. Some JDBC drivers default to a reasonable fetch size, others default to fetching all rows into memory prior to passing them to the client.

Comment: I am using stream to avoid using too much memory. It won't save any memory as you say.  Any suggestions to archive that? 

I also tried to use ResultQuery.fetchlazy and ResultQuery.fetchsize. ResultQuery.fetchlazy is also slow.

Comment: @LongxingWei: 1) Java Stream != Scala Stream. 2) Could you edit your question and post your entire query? If `fetchLazy()` is still slow, then it's probably just a matter of tuning your SQL

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to fetch the records lazily and construct the a scala stream. For example:

```
def allRecords():Stream[Record] = {
  val cur = expression.fetchLazy()
  def inner(): Stream[Record] = {
    if(cur.hasNext) {
      val next =  cur.fetchOne
      next #:: inner()
    }
    else
      Stream.empty
    }
  inner()
}
```